# Git auto transform html file lf to crlf

Tags: git, newline, core.autocrlf

when git push file ,All html was transformed ,Only html file,Git transform LF to CRLF

My git config:

```
$ git config --global --list
user.email=xxx@163.com
user.ename=Jarrem
core.longpaths=true
core.quotepath=false
core.filemode=false
core.autocrlf=input
core.safecrlf=false
```

My Idea config:

```
Line separator : Unix and OS(\n)
```

Comment: The problem you reported literally cannot occur: Git *can not* modify a file during push. Git pushes only *commits* and commits are frozen. Git will do LF-to-CRLF conversion when *extracting* a file, so someone who *received* a push that has an LF-line-ending file in a commit could extract that commit to a work-tree file that has CRLF endings. That would be a problem in the system that is doing the extracting, and not a problem in the Git that is running `git push`. (See also [ask]: the information you have provided is not enough to reproduce the problem.)